# How To Position Chart in Workbook

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, charts, openpyxl

I am running python2.7, and using openpyxl version 1.8.6.  I am able to generate a chart just fine, but am unable to locate anything that indicates the chart can then be positioned in a particular location in a sheet.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

I am using the following code to generate the chart:

```
ws = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Traffic Data')
rowcount = ws.get_highest_row()
values = Reference(ws,(1,1), (rowcount - 1,1))
labels = Reference(ws,(0,1),(rowcount,0))
title = "Events recorded in " + str(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(runmonth), '%m').strftime('%B'))
series = Series(values, title=title)
chart.add_series(series)
ws = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Traffic Incidents')
ws.add_chart(chart)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/src/41512d19430e1e43ff82ef4e782da6271c84f341/openpyxl/worksheet.py?at=default) it is not possible to set the exact location of the chart while adding it to the worksheet using [`add_chart()`](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/api.html#openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.add_chart).

Consider switching to the [`xlsxwriter`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) module. Quote from [Working with Charts](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_charts.html):

```
# Create a new chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Add a series to the chart.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('C1', chart)
```

Comment: What is preventing me from doing this is XLSXwriter's inability to write to an existing spreadsheet.  What is throwing me off though is the following taken from openpyxl code:  def point_pos(self, left=0, top=0):
        """ tells which cell is under the given coordinates (in pixels)
        counting from the top-left corner of the sheet.
        Can be used to locate images and charts on the worksheet """

Comment: @tjm426 yeah, I've noticed the method too, but what it does - is just [returning the position](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/src/e4210c04de7d06a724ec1288b40b1e794a729392/openpyxl/worksheet.py?LC1029#cl-1029), not setting it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to offset the chart position by using chart.drawing. Specifically, I used:

chart.drawing.left = 1000

This offset the chart by about 11 cells. I'm not sure about the pixel to cell mapping, but it can be easily reverse engineered by a few trials.

Comment: There is no reliable pixel to cell mapping because cell sizes are dependent upon the OS when the file is opened.

openpyxl 2.3 allows the use of the different anchors (oneCell, TwoCell, absolute) for placing charts in worksheets.

Answer (score -1):

It's actually really difficult to set the position of any object in Excel because it uses an absurdly stupid system for cell widths: these are based on the width of a number of characters in a particular font and size plus some padding. Charts on the other hand have to be positioned using pixels. We do have the `point_pos()` method in worksheets but I wouldn't trust it. We've just release 2.0 which has cleaner code. Basically you can play around with the `chart.drawing` attributes to get it where you need at in what size.

Take look at the code in charts/chart.py for more information. The next release should be a bit more comfortable.