# Openpyxl Chart anchor: how to use a custom one?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using this code right now, which adds a chart into the first column:

```
ws.add_chart(chart, "A34")
```

However, I'd like to indent the chart by roughly half-column. How can I do this?

Right now, it seems I can only anchor the chart to a cell.

Edit: the linked "duplicate" question no longer applies since the API was changed by version 2.6.0, and the API used in the answer is no longer valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Position Chart in Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617280/how-to-position-chart-in-workbook)

Comment: The API for anchors didn't change with 2.6. Basically you can pass in your own anchor. For documentation on things like offsets you should refer to OOXML specification.

Comment: @CharlieClark So can you confirm that currently it's only possible to anchor to cells via the API, and to anchor on pixels I'd have to modify the XML directly? Can I modify the XML semi-directly via the API?